# Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, deployment

Help me! Enter "mina deploy" get this beauty:

My "/home/deploy/inscope/shared/config/database.yml" looks:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ***
  username: ***
  password: ***
  host: localhost

rake aborted!
   Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:190:in `rescue in spec'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:187:in `spec'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `require_environment!'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Gem::LoadError: pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
   /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:261:in `block in replace_gem'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `spec'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `require_environment!'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737137923106/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

!     ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
       Unlinking current 
       OK

!     Command failed.
       Failed with status 19

Comment: Can you show what you have in your gem file? Did you specify the gem 'pg'?

Comment: 'pg' added, Gemfile: `gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development`

Comment: And I guess it still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. Above found another red line. `/home/deploy/inscope/tmp/build-142737353426931/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now`

Comment: Are you using compass? If yes, this was an [issue](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1902) not so long ago. They fixed it as of now. Otherwise, try updating your Rails version to at least 4.1.9.

Comment: Try to leave off `, group: :production` from your `gem 'pg'` line.

Answer (score -3):

You have to add

```
gem 'pg'
```

In your `GEMFILE`, and you can see it in first row of error:

```
    Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, 
but the gem is not loaded.
 Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```